# QGIS autoincrementing primary key, unique constraint error

Tags: qgis, spatialite, autoincrement

We changed our format for our layers from GPKG to SpatiaLite. A few Layers made some problems with an unique constraint error. Funny thing, saving them as SpatiaLite again did the job most of the time.

Lately I created a SpatiaLite and the same problem occured. "create an autoincrementing primary key" was on. filling the primary key myself worked but the "automatic created" from the program didn't fill it right I guess. I wanted to recreate the error yesterday but they creating of a SpatiaLite layer worked flawless. I can't find much to this error and have no clue what the reason for this problem is. We have no local installation. The program and the SpatiaLites are on the server.

Comment: Do you have several users updating the same GeoPackage or SpatiaLite db?

Comment: yes. That was the reason we switched from GeoPackage to SpatiaLite.

Comment: What to you think that you gain from that change? They are both SQLite databases and they should not be used from network drives by multiple users if that is what you have now https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html.

Comment: With GPKG there was the problem with Qgis crashing from time to time, but with SpatialLite we didnt have that problem anymore. Ty, for the link. I will discuss this with the responsible Person.

Comment: We went through you link and decided to stay with SpatiaLite because there are rarely two persons or more changing Data in the same SpatiaLite. However, i want to understand why this strange problem with the id occurs from time to time. Why does it have the problem to fill the primary key?